# Reading the Object data results in Undefined but key are read correctly

Tags: javascript, json, object, stringify, jsonparser

I have a Object which has values in following format:

```
    [
  {
    NameSpace: 'furuuqu',
    LocalName: 'uuurur',
    ExtensionVlaues: 0,
    FreeText: 'OEN',
    '$$hashKey': 'object:291'
  },
  {
    NameSpace: 'furuuqu',
    LocalName: 'uuurur',
    ExtensionVlaues: 1,
    FreeText: 'TWO',
    '$$hashKey': 'object:293'
  }
]
```

I want to read the data from this so I tried to convert it into JSON using `JSON.stringfy` and the objects would appear something like this:

```
{"NameSpace":"furuuqu","LocalName":"uuurur","ExtensionVlaues":0,"FreeText":"OEN","$$hashKey":"object:291"}
{"NameSpace":"furuuqu","LocalName":"uuurur","ExtensionVlaues":1,"FreeText":"TWO","$$hashKey":"object:293"}
```

I tried looping through this and get the elements but it is displaying the each element for key something like this:

```
Object.keys(extension).forEach(function(key) {
                  console.log(key, extension[key]);
                });

0 {
1 "
2 N
3 a
4 m
5 e
```

If I don't do `JSON.stringify` then the results in `undefined` but the keys are read correctly.

```
for(var ex=0; ex<Extension.length; ex++)
{
    //var extension = JSON.stringify(Extension[ex]);
    
    Object.keys(Extension[ex]).forEach(function(key) {
      console.log(key, extension[key]);
    });
}

NameSpace undefined
LocalName undefined
ExtensionVlaues undefined
FreeText undefined
$$hashKey undefined
NameSpace undefined
LocalName undefined
ExtensionVlaues undefined
FreeText undefined
$$hashKey undefined
```

Can someone please let me know how can I read the data and display in this case.

Comment: Are you sure you need to JSON.parse it? I think it is simply an object at that point and no longer JSON. Try `var extension = Query.Extension[ex]`

Comment: That's quite an exotic format you're using. Normally you would make the array and JSON.stringify the whole thing, not each individual object separately inside the array.

Comment: @slebetman If I do not `JSON.parse` it then i am getting the `undefined` for all the properties. Here is the console example: `console.log(Query.Extension[ex]["NameSpace"]);` and also for `console.log(Query.Extension[ex].NameSpace);`

Comment: @GuyIncognito I am sending my data like this in the angularjs HTTP request: `params: {input:$scope.formdata,Extension:$scope.ExtensionList} `. Is there a better method so send and read the data is so can you please give me an example.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const queryData = [].concat(Query.Extension);
```

use `queryData` to loop，then u don't need to care whether `Query.Extension` is an Array or not

Comment: But this would just push the element to array right and I am reading again the same things from array so I feel this would not make any changes to what data I am reading.

Comment: `Array.concat` accept single element or an array, and return a new array,so `queryData` is always an array.